# error executing bank card payment paypal express checkout javascript

Tags: paypal, express-checkout

I try to integrate paypal express checkout on my application.
when I use a paypal account to pay, it works.

When I choose not to use a paypal account but pay by credit card and not creating an account (on the sandbox) when I click on the "pay now" button, it "processes" for a while and return to the "PayPal Guest Checkout"

when looking at the browser console log, I got the next error on my client side.

```
POST https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/xoonboarding/api/onboard/guest 400 (Bad Request)
```

[image: google chrome error]

I use the javascript checkout sdk on my client side:

the test paypal payment id is: "PAY-0TR22559BT642343YLD4EHJA"

Answer (score 0):

Are you still facing this issue? If you're, can you file an MTS ticket and send to them? They usually will be able to investigate through your sandbox account and see if there's any issue with the account or the integration.

https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/